# Issues with upgrading iPhone4 to iOS 6

Tags: macos, itunes, iphone, upgrade, ios

When I last upgrade my iPhone 4 to iOS 5, I later had to install another version of iTunes on my macbook to synchronize my files between my computer and my iPhone. This new version of iTunes required a new version of Quick Time, which took me a long time to find available on the internet.

Now my iPhone says that I need to upgrade to iOS 6. My macbook runs on Mac OS X leopard (10.5.8).

Which issues should I be aware of when upgrading to iOS 6, given my macbook's limitations?

Answer (score 1):

A big one, as iOS 6 support was added to **iTunes 10.7** which is only supported on **10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)** or later.

So, sadly, since iOS 6 requires this iTunes version to sync, and it requires Snow Leopard to run, your only option would be to upgrade your SO to 10.6.